# How can I fix orphaned holes error in ```LoCoH.a()``` home range calculation?

Tags: r, gps, geospatial, spatial

I am using  a for loop to cycle through multiple animal's GPS data and create `LoCoH.a()` home ranges for each. Some are working fine while others are producing `Error in rgeos::createPolygonsComment(oobj) :  rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon for hole at index 3`. What does this mean and how can I fix it? Searching the internet has not helped. Data for single problem animal and code with annotations below. Thanks

```
rgdal::rgdal_extSoftVersion()
```

GDAL GDAL_with_GEOS PROJ sp EPSG "3.2.1" "TRUE" "7.2.1" "1.4-6" "v10.008"

```
structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "A82121", class = "factor"), DateTime = structure(c(1553092200, 
1553094000, 1553095800, 1553097600, 1553099400, 1553101200, 1553103000, 
1553104800, 1553106600, 1553108400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "CST6CDT"), Longitude = c(-97.4558772, -97.4559166, 
-97.455869, -97.4558304, -97.4693728, -97.4696599, -97.4695082, 
-97.4695069, -97.4732448, -97.4762857), Latitude = c(26.5854647, 
26.5854914, 26.5854211, 26.5853658, 26.5913494, 26.5923971, 26.5924583, 
26.5924705, 26.5939972, 26.5966241)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
library(sp)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(plyr)

for(j in 1:length(collars)) {
  collarIDs <- unique(collars$Id)
  
  for(i in 1:length(collarIDs)) { 
    collarID <- collarIDs[i]
    collar <- filter(collars, Id == collarID)
    
    #coerce to spatialpointsdataframe and reproject
    dat.sp<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=collar[c('Longitude', 'Latitude')],data=collar,
                                   proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
    
    dat.proj <- spTransform(dat.sp, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))
    
    # For LocoH.a, we need to determine greatest distance between 
    # any two points to set a per Getz et al. (2007).
    # To do so, we first calculate 100% mcp because 
    # we know that the two farthest points from one
    # another will be a part of the MCP.
    #creating 100% mcp to parameterize our LoCoH-a
    dat.mcp<-mcp(dat.sp,percent=100)
    dat.mcp<-spTransform(dat.mcp, CRS('+proj=utm +zone=14 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs'))
    
    # Make a data frame out of the coordinates of the MCP vertices
    df.mcp<-data.frame(dat.mcp@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
    
    # Create empty vector to fill with maximum value from each list of distances
    maxdist<-rep(NA,1)
    
    # Cycle through each vertex and get a list of distances to each other vertex, then
    # add the greatest distance to the empty vector 'maxdist'
    #embedded this loop in our main loop
    #going through location number, not id
    k<-1 
    for(k in 1:length(maxdist)){
      maxdist[k]<-max(spDistsN1(pts=as.matrix(df.mcp[,c('X1','X2')]), pt=c(df.mcp[k,'X1'],df.mcp[k,'X2']), longlat=F))
    }
  
    # Make a variable to be uses as the a value in LoCoHa calculations
    aref<-maxdist[k] 
    
    coords.area <- LoCoH.a(dat.proj, a=aref) #orphaned hole error occurs here#
```

Comment: A hole has the opposite winding of it's enclosing polygon (actually this terminology 'winding' may come from postgis), so rgeos, upon finding a hole asks something like, who do you belong to? This may be an artifact of the process of how the polygons were first arrived at. see `?rgeos::createSPComment` Details how rgeos uses gContains to assess parent poly, and says a lot more...

Comment: Thanks for the help. This seems promising, but I am not sure how to incorporate it into my for loop.

Comment: My sense is this aspect of the data has to be addressed before the `for`.

Comment: That is what is confusing me. The data has been cleaned and plotted for visual inspection. I have gotten rid of erroneous points and everything looks good. I don't know what else to do. If I change the ```aref``` value then if fixes some but then others produce the error.

Comment: Just following along, `LoCoH.a(coords.utm`, where is the coords.utm?

Comment: I failed to update that when I edited the post. It should be correct now ```  coords.area <- LoCoH.a(dat.proj, a=aref)```

Comment: [CRS objects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/CRS_warnings.html), what does `rgdal::rgdal_extSoftVersion()` show for you? Mine,  GDAL   "3.5.0dev-af52706a15"      GDAL_with_GEOS   "TRUE"  PROJ "8.2.1" sp  "1.4-6" EPSG
 "v10.041" . Running LoCoH.a in debug to see where rgeos triggers...

Comment: This is what I am getting... GDAL GDAL_with_GEOS           PROJ             sp           EPSG 
       "3.2.1"         "TRUE"        "7.2.1"        "1.4-6"      "v10.008"

Comment: This output will be easier to read if pasted into your question above. `sf` has similar function, useful for future ?'s instead of `sessionInfo()`. And when you run the function below?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, per se, but an approach for debugging troublesome `for` loops, just wrap in a function:

```
source('test_collars2.R')
debugonce(test_collars2)
loco_tst <- test_collars2(collars = collars)
```

Loop as function:

```
test_collars2 <- function(collars) {
collars = collars
for(j in 1:length(collars$Id)) {
   collarIDs <- unique(collars$Id)
  
   for(i in 1:length(collarIDs)) { 
    collarID <- collarIDs[i]
    collar <- filter(collars, 'Id' == 'collarID') # quotes on objects
    
    #coerce to spatialpointsdataframe and reproject - this only needs to be done once
    dat.sp<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=collars[c('Longitude', 'Latitude')],data=collars[,1:2],
                                   proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
    
    dat.proj <- spTransform(dat.sp, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))
    
    #creating 100% mcp to parameterize our LoCoH-a - this only needs to be done once
    dat.mcp<-mcp(dat.sp,percent=100)
    dat.mcp<-spTransform(dat.mcp, CRS('+proj=utm +zone=14 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs'))
    
    # Make a data frame out of the coordinates of the MCP vertices - this only needs to be done once
    df.mcp<-data.frame(dat.mcp@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
    
    # Create empty vector to fill with maximum value from each list of distances - again once
    maxdist<-rep(NA,1)
    
    # Cycle through each vertex and get a list of distances to each other vertex, then
    # add the greatest distance to the empty vector 'maxdist'
    #embedded this loop in our main loop
    #going through location number, not id
    #k<-1 
    # done once
    for(k in 1:length(maxdist)){
      maxdist[k]<-max(spDistsN1(pts=as.matrix(df.mcp[,c('X1','X2')]), pt=c(df.mcp[k,'X1'],df.mcp[k,'X2']), longlat=F))
    }
  
    # Make a variable to be uses as the a value in LoCoHa calculations - done once
    aref<-maxdist
    
    coords.area <- LoCoH.a(dat.proj, a=aref) #orphaned hole error occurs here - done once /per animal
    
    }
    }
    return(c(coords.area = coords.area, maxdist = maxdist, dat.mcp = dat.mcp, dat.proj = dat.proj, dat.sp = dat.sp)) # ?df.mcp = df.mcp.X1, df.mcp.X2 why?
    }
```

the - just done once comments mean per animal, so you should have at least two different animals to check your logic. For one animal, this works given an operating environment of:

```
> rgdal::rgdal_extSoftVersion()
                 GDAL        GDAL_with_GEOS                  PROJ 
"3.5.0dev-af52706a15"                "TRUE"               "8.2.1" 
                   sp                  EPSG 
              "1.4-6"             "v10.041"
```

Two animals please, where you will have to start giving some thought to your [i, j] notation at each function, yikes...